# Populating a table based on values chosen from a drop down in struts2 application

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a drop down in a jsp page having the following code

```
<s:select name="newQuestion.CertificationId"
    list="certificationList"
    listKey="certificationId"
    listValue="certificationName"
    headerKey=""
    headerValue="Select Certification"
    label="Certification Name"
    onchange="getQuestionsList(this.value)" />
```

Now the on change event of the drop down is calling a JS function getQuestionsList() which intends to fetch the question list of the certification Id choosen.

In the JS function I am submitting it to a action class where I am doing a DB call to fetch question list based on values of certification Id

```
function getQuestionDetails(value){
    var submiturl = "Action1.action?certId="+value;

$.ajax({
    url:submiturl,
    type: 'get',
    beforeSend: function(){
        $("#loading").show();
        alert("parsed");
    },  
    success: function(result){
        if(result!=''){

        } else {
            alert(result);
        }
    },
  });
}
```

Now in the action class I am setting the value of questionList with values I fetch from database .questionList is a instance variable in action class with getter and setter methods.Now in struts.xml I am passing to the same jsp where I had the drop down

```
<action name="questionAction" class="questionInfo.QuestionManager"
            method="displaySelectedQuestions">
    <result name="loaded">/questionAdmin.jsp</result>
</action>
```

The problem I encounter is when I go back to the jsp I am not able to retrieve the question List which I display in an iterator

```
<table class="registrationDetailsTable">
    <tr class="tabledataheader">
        <td>Question Id</td>
        <td>Question Description</td>
    </tr>
    <s:iterator value="questionList">
        <tr class="tabledatarow">
            <td><s:property value="questionId" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="questionDesc" /></td>        
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</table>
```

Please let me know where I am getting wrong so that I have the question List populated in my jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call your action with `$.ajax(...)`, the action creates the response by forwarding to the view (questionAdmin.jsp), right? And this response should be available to you in that Ajax call's return value handler.

So when you have this:

```
success: function(result){
        if(result!=''){
            // nothing here currently!
        } else {
            alert(result);
        }
    }
```

You should do something with the resulting HTML. You could begin by doing just `alert(result)` to see what you are getting and then display the new list contents using Javascript. I would do it so that you have a div containing your table like this:

```
<div id="myTableWrapper"> <!-- I added this div -->
    <!-- This part should come from the action when called by Ajax -->
    <table class="registrationDetailsTable">
        <tr class="tabledataheader">
            <td>Question Id</td>
            <td>Question Description</td>
        </tr>
       <tr class="tabledatarow">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>My question #1</td>        
        </tr>
        <tr class="tabledatarow">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>My question #2</td>        
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- //This part should come from the action when called by Ajax -->
</div>
```

So now you can do this:

```
success: function(result){
        if(result!=''){
            $('.myTableWrapper').html(result);
        } else {
            alert(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I print the result in the ajax call made above,I get the source code for questionAdmin.jsp.

Comment: In the above action class QuestionManager ,I am fetching the question list from DB using the question Id passed in the url and have set the same using a setter method of questionList which is a instance varaible for this action class

Comment: @Sam Isn't the questionAdmin.jsp producing the correct output? Can you update your table's HTML with that output? I'm not sure how to help further, as I don't understand what your problem really is at this point. You should be able to 1) Load your list with initial values 2) Select an id, send it as an Ajax call to your action and 3) display the result (=the changed list) of that call on your page using Javascript.

Comment: Thnx Delta for all your help.I managed to extract the part of output and override the html of that part only ..