# send argument from jsp to struts2 action class's method

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

this is the continuation of the following  2 links .... due to I was unable to post any comments for these...

> 1.
>   [Populating a table based on values chosen from a drop down in struts2 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310367/populating-a-table-based-on-values-choosen-from-a-drop-down-in-struts2-applicati?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

**and**

> 2.
>   [Struts2 parameter to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971559/struts2-parameter-to-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top)

I too have the same scenario where i need to print a table based on the selected value from the drop down list, in my google search I got this page and I used suggestions here. But when I select a value in my drop down list I get on table printed and the page still staying in the same page without any updation and below is my code ...help me out in this...

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showAllocationStatusJavaScript(){

    var batchURL1="<s:property value="#batchURL"/>";
    $.ajax({
        url:batchURL1,
        type: 'get',
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#loading").show();
            alert("parsed");
        },  
        success: function(result){
            if(result!=''){
        $('myTableWrapper').html(result);
            } else {
                alert(result);
            }
        },
      });
       }

</script>
```

**inside the jsp body**

```
<s:select label="Select Batch" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select a Batch..."list="%{#session.Batchs}" Value="batch"  name="batch"  onchange="showAllocationStatusJavaScript()" id="batch"/>
```

**URL Tag**

```
<s:url action="doShowAllocationStatus" var="batchURL"><param value="%{batch}"/></s:url>
```

**this the table to print my list**

```
<div id="myTableWrapper">
<table align="center" border="2">
  <tr>
    <th>TAN</th>
    <th>Curator</th>
    <th>Curator Status</th>
    <th>QC</th>
    <th>QC Status</th>
  </tr>
  <s:iterator value="allocationList" >
  <tr>
    <td><s:property value="tan"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="curator"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="curator_status"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="qc"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="qc_status"/></td>
  </tr>
  </s:iterator>
</table>
</div>
```

**struts.xml**

```
 <action name="doShowAllocationStatus" class="controller.AllocateTAN" method="showAllocationStatus" >
  <result name="success" type="dispatcher" >Allocation.jsp</result>
```

**AllocateTAN action class**

```
//Fields that hold data...
    private List<BatchInfo> allocationList =new ArrayList<BatchInfo>();
    private String batch;
    private List<String> batchs = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String TAN;
    private List<String> Tans = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String user;
    private List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();

//and all getters and setters....

.....

//variable used to access DataBase...
    CationDAO dao1 = new CationDAO() ;



//flow 1.: making all details available for the allocate TAN page...when page page is loaded 1st time


    public String AllocatingTANpageDetails() throws SQLException{
        Map<String, Object>session=ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
        this.batchs=dao1.Batch_List();
        session.put("Batchs", batchs);
        //Tans=dao1.Tan_list(getBatch());
        this.users=dao1.Users_List();
        session.put("users", users);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    private void showTANlist(String Batch1) throws SQLException{
        Map<String, Object>session=ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
        Tans=dao1.Tan_list(Batch1);
        session.put("Tans", Tans);

    }
//flow 2.: showing Allocation Status in Table form...in same page


    public String showAllocationStatus() throws SQLException {
        Map<String, Object>session=ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
        //setBatch(batch_value);
        session.put("Batch",batch);

        showTANlist(batch);
        System.out.println("Processing Allocation List... ");
        this.allocationList=(List<BatchInfo>)dao1.status(batch);
        System.out.println("Finished...");
        return SUCCESS;
        }

//execute method form allocating a TAN for a user...    
    public String execute(){

        return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Are you updating the allocationList on Action class??

Comment: additionally show us the action class code

Comment: try what Dave has suggested..i should work

Comment: ya I tried and now got doubt in the URL Tag so I had add it to my code please see to it.

Comment: you are using following tag to create URL <s:url action="doShowAllocationStatus" var="batchURL"><param value="%{batch}"/></s:url> what exactly the URL is coming out can you show by suing an alter for batchURL1??

Comment: It is calling my method inside my action class along with this I have passed a argument "batch" which is the value selected from batch drop down list.

Comment: @umesh awashi                                                              '_success: function(result){
            if(result!=''){
        $('myTableWrapper').html(result);
            } else {
                alert(result);
            }_'  In this code what is the use of "result" any is it any predefined constant?

Comment: result is the result being send back by your action class.you should be the one returning this from you action class.

Comment: @umesh awashi:  Now I'm clear with all these. But the worst part is these codes are doing noting in my page and I dont even get any error so I cant find what would gone wrong.

Comment: Use Debugger to check what exactly you are getting in request and what you raction class is returning

Comment: @umesh awashi: when I run debug I got this msg....Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor. so I changed the server time even though it is not starting in debug mode.. Y?

Comment: just goggle how to use debugger in eclipse and check if anything is blocking tomcat from starting

Comment: @umesh awashi: Thanks for your all guidance, at last if achieved what I want. I posted the answer please do look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery selector is incorrect:

```
$('myTableWrapper').html(result);
```

DOM element IDs are specified by a leading `#` character; this should be:

```
$('#myTableWrapper').html(result);
```

You also have an extraneous trailing comma in your `$.ajax` arguments, which will break on some browsers and should always be eliminated.

```
function showAllocationStatusJavaScript() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<s:property value='#batchURL'/>",
        type: 'get',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#loading").show();
        },
        success: function(result) {
            if (result != '') {
                $('#myTableWrapper').html(result);
            }
            $("#loading").hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ok let me try it out tomorrow. and I needed say that i'm new to stuts2 and ajax. Here I added my action class now, I hope every thing is correct in my action class and if any correction is required please let me know.

Comment: I still did't get the table printed and I think I'm wrong in using url tag... 

<s:url action="doShowAllocationStatus" var="batchURL"><param value="%{batch}"/></s:url>

this the url tag that send the parameter to the action class that which has my method "showAllocationStatus". and where should i supposed to write this URL Tag in my jsp

Also I have a doubt that you had said that 

$('myTableWrapper').html(result); //is wrong 
and 
$('#myTableWrapper').html(result); //is correct

and gave me corrected code for my ajax code.
In this code you have in't used "#" ? y?

Comment: @SathishKumarkk Typo; fixed. You can look at the rendered HTML to make sure everything is set correctly.

Comment: ok but you have answered me for the last 2 lines of my above comment, I request you to solve my doubt about placing the URL Tag. and another one thing is do I need to include any taglib and jar files. I have read In some forum that struts2 to has all ajax code is it so?

Comment: @SathishKumarkk S2 has the deprecated Dojo tags, and at least two different jQuery tag libraries. For using raw  jQuery there are no additional taglibs or jars required, it's just JavaScript. I told you that looking st the rendered HTML will indicate if it's being used correctly.

Comment: I have seen the HTML rendering, I did't get any idea. I can't find where I'm stuck. I hope you got what was my requirement. I need to print a table based on the value selected form the drop down list.

Comment: @Dᴀᴠᴇ Nᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ: Thanks for all your guidance, I got the result and it need some little change. I have posted those changes as answer... please do look at it....

Comment: @Dᴀᴠᴇ Nᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ: in your code you have used .html() to get the content from the action and I too use the same, but a new problem is that it returns the same page again, i.e, in the browser I was able to see the same drop down list again. so there are 2 drop down list and a table. what I need is to only load the table content each time. how to do it?

Comment: @SathishKumarkk You need to make the request to a URL that returns only the HTML or data you want.

Comment: @Dᴀᴠᴇ Nᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ: do u mean data() in jquery? I tried that in the place of html(), but failed. can you give me some code for only updating the table data and also elements of the page like textarea, dropdown list,etc.,

Answer (score 0):

At last I found the Answer...
 there are some corrections I did in my jquery-ajax code and struts.xml...here they are...

**jquery-ajax code**

```
<head>
<script type="javascript" src="jquery-1.7.js"></script>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#batchID').change(function(event) {
                var batch=$('#batchID').val();
                alert("inside change fn."+batch);
                $.ajax({
                    url     : "doShowAllocationStatus.action",
                    data    : "batch="+batch,
                    success : function(html) {
                        alert("success");
                                $("#table").html(html);
                                },
                    error   : function(html) {
                                alert("error");
                                }
                      });
            });
        });     
</script>
```

**now here I wrote the table code that which I shown in above question, in a new jsp page(AllocationStatusTable.jsp) and included it...**

```
<div id=table>
<s:include value="AllocationStatusTable.jsp" />
</div>
```

Later in struts.xml I re-wrote the action configuration as,

```
<action name="doShowAllocationStatus" class="controller.AllocateTAN" method="showAllocationStatus" >
  <result name="input" >Allocation.jsp</result> 
   <result name="error" >Allocation.jsp</result>
  <result>AllocationStatusTable.jsp</result>
   </action>
```

so the result of the action is pointed to the new jsp page (AllocationStatusTable.jsp).

**Finally when I select a batch in my brop down list I will get my table according to my batch selected...  :)**