# How can we pass a list from jsp to Actionclass in struts2?

Tags: struts2

How can we pass a list from JSP to the action in Struts 2?

The list is a list of strings set from the same action when the JSP page gets loaded (there is a hidden field in the JSP which is being set).

All that I need is when again the form is submitted and the control goes to the action, I need that list again.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149882/send-argument-from-jsp-to-struts2-action-classs-method.It might be useful for u

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of strings and submit it using json or make a # seperated string of all strings and associate it with some hidden variable and submit it to action class. then in action class you needs to parse it back to original form.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the hidden tag name attribute to refer to the list name that is being used in the class. Now when the form is submitted it will automatically map to the list in your action.

You need to have list as your instance variable in the action class

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting a *single* hidden field with the contents of a list then you'll need to parse it back into a list again. Whether or not this is a good idea depends on the contents of the list, and how good you are at parsing.

Another option is to use Struts 2's default list-building mechanism and use multiple hidden fields and OGNL's array notation, e.g., `name="foo[0]"`, `name="foo[1]"`, and so on.

I'd start, however, by examining the need to reconstruct the list from the JSP like this.

If you're just serializing/deserializing the same list, why bother? Either keep it in session, or reconstruct it on the Java side. If it's backed by a DB then your caching mechanism should reduce any overhead.